# Java+Kotlin Jar only runs with Gradle application plugin

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I have a Kotlin command line application and I am using the Gradle [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) to build a stand alone tool.  Everything works fine when I use the `./gradlew run` command.  However when run directly using java the application silently exits with no indication of an error.

I have double checked my class path and my main application name.  What else could be wrong here, I feel like it is something obvious.  Thanks for the help.

```
> java -verbose:class -classpath $CLASSPATH com.amazon.rubrik.cli.Main
[Opened /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
....
....
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$EntryIterator from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$MapEntry from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]

> echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the application requires a system property to be defined in order to run.  The property was buried deep in gradle files.